# Excessive memory operations, can I borrow as mutable all the way down the chain?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to borrow as mutable all the way down the chain and return ownership to `config`? The memory operations here seem really excessive to update a single variable.

The code is working as expected but coming from high level languages it seems a little "hacky". Am I on the right track? The documentation is a little sparse on this library.

```
// Read Config File
let mut file = File::open("config.yaml").unwrap();
let mut contents = String::new();
file.read_to_string(&mut contents);

// Get Mutable 'endpoints'
let mut docs = YamlLoader::load_from_str(&contents).unwrap();
let mut config = docs[0].as_hash().unwrap().clone();
let mut endpoints = config[&Yaml::from_str("endpoints")].as_vec().unwrap().clone();


// Find the correct 'endpoint'
for (i, endpoint) in endpoints.clone().iter().enumerate() {
    let mut endpoint = endpoint.as_hash().unwrap().clone();
    
    if endpoint[&Yaml::from_str("name")] == Yaml::from_str("Current Name") {
        // Found the endpoint, let's update it's name
        endpoint.insert(Yaml::from_str("name"), Yaml::from_str("New Name"));
        endpoints.insert(i, Yaml::Hash(endpoint));
        config.insert(Yaml::from_str("endpoints"), Yaml::Array(endpoints.clone()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure at all, but I would try using `as_mut` on the options I guess. Doubtful it'll work the whole way though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and I did try using `as_mut`. However i kept running into this error: `temporary value dropped while borrowed, consider using a 'let' binding to create a longer lived value` This does not work: `docs[0].as_hash().as_mut().unwrap();`  Am I using `as_mut` incorrectly? I think `unwrap` may be to blame here?

Comment: `unwrap` would be causing the errors. But I'm not sure what to do here... The other possibilty would be to use an `if let` or a `match` to take out the values?

Comment: after playing around a bit more. It seems 'as_hash' always returns an immutable borrow. The library also exposes `into_hash()`, but it looks like this attempts to move it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of `match`. Using this in combination with `borrow_mut` seems to be doing exactly what I was looking for. From what I can tell this should avoid duplicating any data in memory now correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is working, and I think solves all the pitfalls of my previous code.

```
let mut docs = YamlLoader::load_from_str(&contents).unwrap();
let mut config = docs[0].borrow_mut();

if let Yaml::Hash(hash_map) = config {
    if let Yaml::Array(endpoints) = hash_map[&Yaml::from_str("endpoints")].borrow_mut() {
        for endpoint in endpoints.iter_mut() {
            if let Yaml::Hash(endpoint) = endpoint.borrow_mut() {
                if endpoint[&Yaml::from_str("name")] == Yaml::from_str("Current Name") {
                    endpoint.insert(Yaml::from_str("name"), Yaml::from_str("New Name"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```